# Git Merge indicates branch is already up to date

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to solve a Git merge issue. I have a Dev_R1 branch with a common.cs file and then another branch of Dev_R1 called B1. The same .cs file has been updated in branch B1 where a function has been re-written.

As I try to merge B1 into Dev_R1 it gives me the "Already up to date" message. I'm using gitlab extension in Visual Studio 2017 but would be okay with any command line options to solve the issue.

Comment: where in the graph in relation to each other do these branches reside?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+merge+says+branch+already+up+to+date

Comment: Dev_R1 is a parent of B1 branch while Dev_R1 is a child of master. Also I don't want to repalce the file in Dev_R1 as this might mess up work from others

Comment: Branches do not have parent/child relationships. Only commits have parent/child relationships.

Comment: Can you give us a graph view of the commits (preferably simplified)?

Comment: command `git log --oneline --decorate --boundary B1...Dev_R1` would give you the relevant piece of history. Please provide it